# how to skip some file type while crawling with scrapy?

Tags: mime, scrapy

I want to skip some file type link .exe .zip .pdf while crawling with scrapy, but don't want to use Rule with specific url regular. How?

Update:

Due to that it's hard to decide whether to follow this link just by Content-Type in response when the body hasn't been downloaded. I change to drop url in downloader middleware. thanks Peter and Leo.

Answer (score 16):

If you go to linkextractor.py within the Scrapy root directory, you will see the following:

```
"""
Common code and definitions used by Link extractors (located in
scrapy.contrib.linkextractor).
"""

# common file extensions that are not followed if they occur in links
IGNORED_EXTENSIONS = [
    # images
    'mng', 'pct', 'bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pst', 'psp', 'tif',
    'tiff', 'ai', 'drw', 'dxf', 'eps', 'ps', 'svg',

    # audio
    'mp3', 'wma', 'ogg', 'wav', 'ra', 'aac', 'mid', 'au', 'aiff',

    # video
    '3gp', 'asf', 'asx', 'avi', 'mov', 'mp4', 'mpg', 'qt', 'rm', 'swf', 'wmv',
    'm4a',

    # other
    'css', 'pdf', 'doc', 'exe', 'bin', 'rss', 'zip', 'rar',
]
```

However, since this applies to the linkextractor (and you don't want to use Rules), I am not sure that this will solve your problem (I just realized you specified that you didn't want to use Rules. I thought you had asked how to change the file-extension restrictions without needing to specify directly in a rule).

The good news is, you can also build your own downloader middleware and drop any/all requests to urls which have an undesirable extension. See [Downloader Middlerware](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html)

You can get the requested url by accessing the `request` object's url attribute as follows: `request.url`

Basically, search the end of the string for '.exe' or whatever extension you want to drop, and if it contains said extentions, return an `IgnoreRequest` exception, and the request will immediately be dropped.

**UPDATE**

In order to process the request prior to it being downloaded, you need to make sure you define the 'process_request' method within your custom downloader middleware.

According to the Scrapy documentation

`process_request`

> This method is called for each request that goes through the download
>   middleware.
>
> process_request() should return either None, a Response object, or a
>   Request object.
>
> If it returns None, Scrapy will continue processing this request,
>   executing all other middlewares until,  finally, the appropriate
>   downloader handler is called the request performed (and its response
>   downloaded).
>
> If it returns a Response object, Scrapy won’t bother calling ANY other
>   request or exception middleware,  or the appropriate download
>   function; it’ll return that Response. Response middleware is always
>   called on  every Response.
>
> If it returns a Request object, the returned request will be
>   rescheduled (in the Scheduler) to be downloaded  in the future. The
>   callback of the original request will always be called. If the new
>   request has a callback  it will be called with the response
>   downloaded, and the output of that callback will then be passed to the
>   original callback. If the new request doesn’t have a callback, the
>   response downloaded will be just passed  to the original request
>   callback.
>
> If it returns an IgnoreRequest exception, the entire request will be
>   dropped completely and its callback never called.

So essentially, just create a downloader class, add a method class process_request, which takes a request object and spider object as parameters. Then return the IgnoreRequest exception if the url contains unwanted extensions.

This should all occur prior to the page being downloaded. However, if you are wanting to process the response headers instead, than a request will have to be made to the webpage.

You could always implement both a process_request and process_response method in the downloader, with the idea being that obvious extensions will immediately be dropped, and than, if for some reason the url did not contain the file extension, the request would be process and caught in the process_request method (since you could verify in the headers)?

Comment: Thank you. I made a downloader middleware and to see if the headers['Content-Type'] in response startswith application. But the problem is this function is called after the whole file is downloaded. It waste a lot. Is that possible to hook before the body of response is transferred?

Comment: Yes. I added a description of how to do it above :P

Comment: I am using rule - `Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True), callback='parse', follow=True, process_request='process_request')`. How can I enable skipping all url with file extension defined in `linkextractor` at once without explicitly mentioning file extension one by one for `deny=()` in above rule?

Comment: @OmPrakash you can do `from scrapy.linkextractors import IGNORED_EXTENSIONS` to get a list of ignored extensions and then add `if req.url.lower().endswith(tuple(IGNORED_EXTENSIONS)):    raise scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest` to your `process_request` function.

Answer (score 5):

.zip and .pdf are [ignored by scrapy by default](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/linkextractor.py).

As a general rule you can either configure a rule to include only urls that match your regexp (.htm* in this case):

```
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\.htm')), callback='parse_page', follow=True, ), )
```

or exclude the ones that match a regexp:

```
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.*'), deny=('\.pdf', '\.zip')), callback='parse_page', follow=True, ), )
```

Read [the documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I built this Middleware to exclude any response type that isn't in a whitelist of regular expressions:

```
from scrapy.http.response.html import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest
from scrapy import log
import re

class FilterResponses(object):
    """Limit the HTTP response types that Scrapy dowloads."""

    @staticmethod
    def is_valid_response(type_whitelist, content_type_header):
        for type_regex in type_whitelist:
            if re.search(type_regex, content_type_header):
                return True
        return False


    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        """
        Only allow HTTP response types that that match the given list of 
        filtering regexs
        """
        # to specify on a per-spider basis
        # type_whitelist = getattr(spider, "response_type_whitelist", None)
        type_whitelist = (r'text', )
        content_type_header = response.headers.get('content-type', None)
        if not content_type_header or not type_whitelist:
            return response

        if self.is_valid_response(type_whitelist, content_type_header):
            return response
        else:
            msg = "Ignoring request {}, content-type was not in whitelist".format(response.url)
            log.msg(msg, level=log.INFO)
            raise IgnoreRequest()
```

To use it, add it to settings.py:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    '[project_name].middlewares.FilterResponses': 999,
}
```