# Python Scrapy - mimetype based filter to avoid non-text file downloads

Tags: python, twisted, mime-types, scrapy

I have a running scrapy project, but it is being bandwidth intensive because it tries to download a lot of binary files (zip, tar, mp3, ..etc).

I think the best solution is to filter the requests based on the mimetype (Content-Type:) HTTP header. I looked at the scrapy code and found this setting:

```
DOWNLOADER_HTTPCLIENTFACTORY = 'scrapy.core.downloader.webclient.ScrapyHTTPClientFactory'
```

I changed it to:
    DOWNLOADER_HTTPCLIENTFACTORY = 'myproject.webclients.ScrapyHTTPClientFactory'

And played a little with the `ScrapyHTTPPageGetter`, here is the edits highlighted:

```
class ScrapyHTTPPageGetter(HTTPClient):
    # this is my edit
    def handleEndHeaders(self):
        if 'Content-Type' in self.headers.keys():
            mimetype = str(self.headers['Content-Type'])
            # Actually I need only the html, but just in 
            # case I've preserved all the text
            if mimetype.find('text/') > -1: 
                # Good, this page is needed
                self.factory.gotHeaders(self.headers)
            else:
                self.factory.noPage(Exception('Incorrect Content-Type'))
```

I feel this is wrong, I need more scrapy friendly way to cancel/drop request right after determining that it's unwanted mimetype. Instead of waiting for the whole data to be downloaded.

**Edit:**
I'm asking specifically for this part `self.factory.noPage(Exception('Incorrect Content-Type'))` is that the correct way to cancel a request.

**Update 1:**
My current setup have crashed the Scrapy server, so please don't try to use the same code above to solve the problem.

**Update 2:**
I have setup an Apache-based website for testing using the following structure:

```
/var/www/scrapper-test/Zend -> /var/www/scrapper-test/Zend.zip (symlink)
/var/www/scrapper-test/Zend.zip
```

I have noticed that Scrapy discards the ones with the `.zip` extension, but scraps the one without .zip even though it's just a symbolic link to it.

Comment: does this actually not work?  handleEndHeaders should get invoked before the body is downloaded

Comment: @fmoo Please see the edit, I've been more specific.

Comment: My current setup have crashed the Scrapy server, so please don't try to use the same code above to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to setup a `Node.js` proxy and configure Scrapy to use it through `http_proxy` environment variable.

What the [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) should do is:

- Take HTTP requests from Scrapy and sends it to the server being crawled. Then it gives back the response from to Scrapy i.e. intercept all HTTP traffic.
- For binary files (based on a heuristic you implement) it sends `403 Forbidden` error to Scrapy and immediate closes the request/response. This helps to save time, traffic and Scrapy won't crash.

#### Sample Proxy Code

That actually works!

```
http.createServer(function(clientReq, clientRes) {
    var options = {
        host: clientReq.headers['host'],
        port: 80,
        path: clientReq.url,
        method: clientReq.method,
        headers: clientReq.headers
    };


    var fullUrl = clientReq.headers['host'] + clientReq.url;
    
    var proxyReq = http.request(options, function(proxyRes) {
        var contentType = proxyRes.headers['content-type'] || '';
        if (!contentType.startsWith('text/')) {
            proxyRes.destroy();            
            var httpForbidden = 403;
            clientRes.writeHead(httpForbidden);
            clientRes.write('Binary download is disabled.');
            clientRes.end();
        }
        
        clientRes.writeHead(proxyRes.statusCode, proxyRes.headers);
        proxyRes.pipe(clientRes);
    });

    proxyReq.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with clientReq: ' + e.message);
    });

    proxyReq.end();
  
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: any option to implement this filter in python twisted or downloader extension ?

Answer (score 11):

I built this Middleware to exclude any response type that isn't in a whitelist of regular expressions:

```
from scrapy.http.response.html import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest
from scrapy import log
import re

class FilterResponses(object):
    """Limit the HTTP response types that Scrapy dowloads."""

    @staticmethod
    def is_valid_response(type_whitelist, content_type_header):
        for type_regex in type_whitelist:
            if re.search(type_regex, content_type_header):
                return True
        return False

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        """
        Only allow HTTP response types that that match the given list of 
        filtering regexs
        """
        # each spider must define the variable response_type_whitelist as an
        # iterable of regular expressions. ex. (r'text', )
        type_whitelist = getattr(spider, "response_type_whitelist", None)
        content_type_header = response.headers.get('content-type', None)
        if not type_whitelist:
            return response
        elif not content_type_header:
            log.msg("no content type header: {}".format(response.url), level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider)
            raise IgnoreRequest()
        elif self.is_valid_response(type_whitelist, content_type_header):
            log.msg("valid response {}".format(response.url), level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider)
            return response
        else:
            msg = "Ignoring request {}, content-type was not in whitelist".format(response.url)
            log.msg(msg, level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider)
            raise IgnoreRequest()
```

To use it, add it to settings.py:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    '[project_name].middlewares.FilterResponses': 999,
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this cancel the files before or after download? i.e. What if a file is of 30GB size, will it cancel immediately after downloading the headers, or it has to wait for the complete response.

Comment: First note the bugs I just corrected. (I had to edit a couple times because I fuddled the markdown). Yes, based on my experiments tossing log messages into this middleware during Scrapy execution, this will stop the response before the file downloads.

Comment: Great. Do you mind keeping the answer bellow as accepted? (instead of your answer)?

Comment: it's all just fake internet points. Just choose whichever you think is the best answer to your question for the sake of future googlers.

Comment: `process_response`? That should hook after the file has been downloaded, or best case right at the beginning of the download. Just use `process_request`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140460/how-to-skip-some-file-type-while-crawling-with-scrapy

Answer (score 0):

May be it is to late. You can use the Accept header to filter the data that you are looking for.

Comment: No it's not, I'm still looking for an answer. What if the server does understand, or ignores the "Accept:" header?

Comment: May be it's a wrong idea. You can split the download process into two stage: 1. A request with HEADER method and 2. if content type is Ok a request with Get method. Best Regards.

Comment: I'm currently trying to do it properly in a Scrapy-friendly way using a downloader Middleware. But splitting the request into two phases is going to complicate the Scrapy setup. I would rather put a webproxy server and do the filtering logic instead of messing with python-twisted.

Comment: I have an another idea. You can define your middleware class with a process_response method that will verify your response in the Downloader class and if the case will generate a new request. You must append this middleware class in the DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES_BASE dictionary of default_settings.py with a  value more 1000.