# CrawlSpider fails to follow rule for some websites

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to start my first scrapy project and I got stuck with a weird problem. For some websites my crawler works well, for some others it does not follow the rule for extracting the links. I searched on SO and saw that other people had similar issues, but in their case the badly formatted their `allow` parameter resulting in a `Filtered offsite request`, which does not happen to me. My logs are here http://pastebin.com/r1pXmeJW (first the failing url, then a url that works fine, because I cannot post more than 2 links...).

My spider is controlled via a Python script that uses the API:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from govcrawl.spiders.main_spider import DomainSpider
import sys, urlparse, re
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor

args = sys.argv[1].split('§')
url_id = args[0]
start_url = args[1]
url_parts = urlparse.urlparse(start_url)
allowed_domain = url_parts.netloc
allowed_path = '/'.join(url_parts.path.split('/')[:-1])
cur_state = sys.argv[2]

spider = DomainSpider(
   start_urls = [start_url],
   allowed_domains = [allowed_domain],
   url_id = url_id,
   cur_state = cur_state,
   rules = (
      Rule(
         LxmlLinkExtractor(
            allow = re.compile(r".*%s.*" % re.escape(allowed_path), re.IGNORECASE),
            allow_domains = [allowed_domain],
            tags = ('a', 'area', 'frame'),
            attrs = ('href', 'src')
         ),
         callback = "parse_items",
         follow = True
      ),
   )
)
settings = get_project_settings()
crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal = signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run()
```

And this is my `DomainSpider`:

```
import re
from govcrawl.items import DomainItem
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy import log

class DomainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "govcrawl_main"

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return self.parse_items(response)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        pages_done = self.crawler.stats.get_value('downloader/response_count')
        pages_todo = self.crawler.stats.get_value('scheduler/enqueued') - self.crawler.stats.get_value('downloader/response_count')
        log.msg("URL: %s (%s) Crawled %d pages. To Crawl: %d" % (self.start_urls[0], self.url_id, pages_done, pages_todo), spider = self)
        links = []
        for sel in response.xpath('//a'):
           href = sel.xpath('@href').extract()
           if len(href) > 0:
              href = href[0]
              if href.startswith("http"):
                 links.append(href)
        item = DomainItem()
        item["url"] = response.url
        item["text"] = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', remove_tags(' '.join(response.xpath('//body//text()').extract()))).strip()
        item["links"] = links
        self.crawler.stats.inc_value('pages_crawled')
        yield item
```

Any idea how to make the crawler follow the rule for the websites that fail?

Comment: With `ìpdb` I was able to put a break here https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/linkextractors/lxmlhtml.py#L97 and saw that in `html` the content of the body is not correct and without links. I **know** that the server is sending me the correct html, so the problem is between the data fetching and the caller of the link extractor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the page returning the error had a malformed html code, with multiple `</html>`s which `lxml` parser didn't like. Since `scrapy` doesn't allow you to use a `CrawlSpider` with a different parser, I ended up reimplementing a regular `Spider` object that behaves more or less as a `CrawlSpider`:

```
import urlparse, re
from scrapy import Spider, log
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.http import Request
from govcrawl.items import DomainItem

class DomainSimpleSpider(Spider):
    name = "govcrawl_simple"

    def parse(self, response):
        pages_done = self.crawler.stats.get_value('downloader/response_count')
        pages_todo = self.crawler.stats.get_value('scheduler/enqueued') - self.crawler.stats.get_value('downloader/response_count')
        log.msg("URL: %s (%s) Crawled %d pages. To Crawl: %d" % (self.start_urls[0], self.url_id, pages_done, pages_todo), spider = self)
        #import ipdb
        #ipdb.set_trace()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response._body, "html5lib")
        links = []
        for tag in self.tags:
           for a in soup.find_all(tag):
              for attr in self.attrs:
                 if attr in a.attrs:
                    href = a.attrs[attr]
                    if href.startswith("http"):
                       links.append(href)
                    href = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, href)
                    href_parts = urlparse.urlparse(href.replace('\t', '').replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '+'))
                    if re.match(self.allow, href_parts.path) and not self.forbidden_extension(href_parts.path):
                       yield Request(href)
        for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
           script.extract()
        item = DomainItem()
        item["url"] = response.url
        #item["text"] = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', remove_tags(' '.join(response.xpath('//body//text()').extract()))).strip()
        item["text"] = soup.get_text()
        item["links"] = links
        self.crawler.stats.inc_value('pages_crawled')
        yield item

    def forbidden_extension(self, url):
       url = url.lower()
       return url.endswith("pdf") or url.endswith("jpg") or url.endswith("wmv") or url.endswith("avi") or url.endswith("pptx") or url.endswith("gif") or url.endswith("mp3") or url.endswith("mp4") or url.endswith("wav") or url.endswith("mov") or url.endswith("ppt") or url.endswith("xls") or url.endswith("doc") or url.endswith("docx") or url.endswith("xlsx") or url.endswith("flv") or url.endswith("wma") or url.endswith("jpeg") or url.endswith("png") or url.endswith("odf") or url.endswith("ods") or url.endswith("zip") or url.endswith("gz") or url.endswith("tar") or url.endswith("7z") or url.endswith("rar") or url.endswith("vob")
```

This spider can be controlled via the following Python script:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from govcrawl.spiders.simple_spider import DomainSimpleSpider
import urlparse, re
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor

start_url = ...
url_parts = urlparse.urlparse(start_url)
allowed_domain = url_parts.netloc
allowed_path = '/'.join(url_parts.path.split('/')[:-1])

spider = DomainSimpleSpider(
   start_urls = [start_url],
   allowed_domains = [allowed_domain],
   allow = re.compile(r".*%s.*" % re.escape(allowed_path), re.IGNORECASE),
   tags = ('a', 'area', 'frame'),
   attrs = ('href', 'src'),
   response_type_whitelist = [r"text/html", r"application/xhtml+xml", r"application/xml"]
)
settings = get_project_settings()
crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal = signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run()
```

Note that:

1. I am using `html5lib` parser from `BeautifulSoup` instead of `lxml`. `html5lib` can handle multiple `</html>` quite nicely, but it's an external dependency, so you'll have to install it.
2. For some reason, the mimetype check seems not working. Therefore I added a `forbidden_extensions` function that prevents the creation of `Request` for non `html` files and I had to add another `DownloaderMiddleware` that makes use of the `response_type_whitelist` of the spider (see [Python Scrapy - mimetype based filter to avoid non-text file downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401382/python-scrapy-mimetype-based-filter-to-avoid-non-text-file-downloads) for the middleware implementation)
3. It seems that this spider is processing the starting page twice, but I frankly don't care to fix this.